# Java JTable TableCellRenderer With ImageIcon Column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a table with a custom table model which has two columns. Column 0 is an ImageIcon class, and Column 1 is a String class.

```
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
    if (col == 0) {
        return ImageIcon.class;
    } else {
        return String.class;
    }
}
```

When I define a new TableCellRenderer class to be added to the columns so I can style the cells, it overwrites the ImageIcon class and sets it to a String.

```
public class CustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable table, Object obj, boolean isSelected,     boolean hasFocus, int row, int 
    column)
    {
    Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, 
      obj, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    if(isSelected)
     cell.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    return cell;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

My mistake, it is sort of hidden:

> When I define a new TableCellRenderer class to be added to the columns so I can style the cells, it overwrites the ImageIcon class and sets it to a String.

So the problem is that, when I define this TableCellRenderer class to style my table, the ImageIcon columns in my table turn to Strings like "File:..." instead of the actual icon.

Comment: I am sorry, but it seems that you have not asked the question. You have just explained what are you doing. Please explain the problem. What's wrong? What does not work?

Comment: Are you sure that it's the renderer you're seeing and not the editor? Does this display of numbers happen for all cells, or only the cell that has focus and is being edited? If the latter, you may need to fiddle with the cell editor.

Comment: Display of what numbers? Because my cell does in fact turn blue on select so I am pretty sure its the renderer.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. On checking on things, the JTable will not use a DefaultCellRenderer when displaying ImageIcons but instead uses something called an IconRenderer. I haven't found this class yet, but am looking.

Comment: Perhaps you want to try Darryl Burke's Icon Cell Renderer?: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/18/icon-table-cell-renderer/

Comment: His solution doesn't really fit my requirements but I did use a suggestion in the comments. Since we need to return a Component I just used a JLabel, set it to opaque(...) add the icon using new JLabel((ImageIcon) table.getValueAt(row, col)). Thanks for the help guys ;D

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to create a custom renderer. JTable allready supports a default renderer for columns containing an Icon. All you need to do is override the getColumnClass() method, which you appear to be doing.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to just set the icon yourself. I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but it works:

```
   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
      Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row,
               column);
      ((JLabel)cell).setIcon((Icon)value);
      ((JLabel)cell).setText("");
      ((JLabel)cell).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      if (isSelected) {
         cell.setBackground(Color.blue);
      } else {
         cell.setBackground(null);
      }
      return cell;
   }
```

Comment: Yeah I just discovered this way a few minutes ago, not too elegant but works perfectly.

Comment: cool. You may also need to set the JLabel's text to "" and the horizontal alignment to center: